# Snakemake: Mismatched Wildcards Variable Values for "output" Rule

Tags: python, wildcard, directory-structure, snakemake, cp

I am encountering a problem that doesn't seem to occur consistently between folders.

Essentially, I thought I had a Snakemake pipeline that would work to copy files into folders (with different destinations for different subfolders).  I am currently accomplishing this with some Python dictionaries as well as 2 wildcard values.

However, I am currently encountering a problem that I believe is due to a mismatch between the `{outf}` and `{sample}` wildcards values.

### Brief Description

I believe that the wildcards are defined with `rule all`:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand(os.path.join("{outf}","{sample}","methods.txt"), outf=OUTPREFIXES, sample=SAMPLES)
```

In the example that I will describe below:

- Pairing of `{outf}` and `{sample}` is **correct** for `input`
- Pairing of `{outf}` and `{sample}` is ***not*** correct in the log output for `output`
- Pairing of `{outf}` and `{sample}` is ***not*** correct in the log output for `wildcards`

### Additional Details

I am removing some details related to the exact formatting, but the code is basically as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import re

data = pd.read_csv("mapping_list.csv").set_index('Subfolder', drop=False)
SAMPLES = data["Subfolder"].tolist()
OUTPREFIXES = data["Output"].tolist()

def get_input_folder(wildcards):
    return data.loc[wildcards.sample]["Input"]

def get_output_folder(wildcards):
    return data.loc[wildcards.sample]["Output"]
    
rule all:
    input:
        expand(os.path.join("{outf}","{sample}","methods.txt"), outf=OUTPREFIXES, sample=SAMPLES)

rule copy_folders:
    input:
        infolder = directory(get_input_folder),
        outfolder = directory(get_output_folder),
    output:
        os.path.join("{outf}","{sample}","methods.txt"),
    resources:
        mem_mb=2000,
        cpus=1
    shell:
        '''
        SHOUT1={input.outfolder}
        ...
        cp -R {input.infolder} $SHOUT1
        
        TEMPSAMPLE=$(basename {input.infolder})
        SHEND={input.outfolder}/$TEMPSAMPLE
        ...
        cp ../methods.txt $SHEND
        '''
```

I am receiving the following error message:

```
Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in line 22 of /path/to/Snakefile:
Missing files after 5 seconds:
[Variable Destination Folder B]/[Sample A]/methods.txt
```

I believe that I can see the problem in an earlier part of the log :

```
rule copy_folders:
    input: /common/folder/path/[Sample A], [Variable Destination Folder A]
    output: [Variable Destination Folder B]/[Sample A]/methods.txt
    jobid: 171
    wildcards: outf=[Variable Destination Folder B], sample=[Sample A]
    resources: mem_mb=2000, cpus=1
```

I have a sample sheet where various folders are paired with a unique sample ID.  On a given line, you would find `[Sample A]` and `[Variable Destination Folder A]`.  On a different line, you would find `[Sample B]` and `[Variable Destination Folder B]`, etc..

**In other words, the mismatch for the `wildcards` at the earlier step matches the error message in that it describes a file that should not be created at that point (because the values for `{outf}` and `{sample}` are not matched correctly, for different lines "A" and "B").**

The *methods.txt* file is not strictly needed.  However, I encountered problems when trying to use a directory as the endpoint, so I copied an extra file and I used that as the endpoint.  If it helps, I can share the earlier code.  However, for 1 different folder with a smaller number of subfolders to copy and less complicated destination folders, something similar to the current code appeared to work successfully.

I had an earlier version of the code to try and make sure that the shell environment variables were "local" to each folder.  I think the use of "local" caused a problem in itself, which an error message indicating that can only be used within a function.

However, if use the similarly simplified portion of the shell code, then the paths *were* filled in as follows:

```
        local SHOUT1=[Variable Destination Folder A]
        ...
        cp -R /common/folder/path/[Sample A] $SHOUT1
        
        local TEMPSAMPLE=$(basename /common/folder/path/[Sample A])
        local SHEND=[Variable Destination Folder A]/$TEMPSAMPLE
        ...
        cp ../methods.txt $SHEND
```

In other words, it looks like **the paths for the shell command were correct** (all for line "A" in the sample mapping file).  I assume this is because they only used `input` wildcards values, because I noticed a problem with the variable mismatching.  Some troubleshooting was added to be able to handle a folder with a space in the name where different parts of the same script need to use *"\ "* versus *" "* to run correctly), but I am excluding those folders to try and simplify the most immediate troubleshooting.  However, I can't run the Snakemake script if I can't specify the `output` value correctly.

**Any assistance with troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated!**

I thought this should be a relatively simple example to start learning Snakemake for what is basically `cp -R $INPUTSUBFOLDER $OUTPUTFOLDER`, but perhaps there are more complications than I realized.

Sincerely,

Charles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks like it pairs the input to your `copy_folders` rule correctly because you're using an input function that only uses your `sample` wildcard to get it. For the output, though, there's a mismatch because if you run the Snakefile without specifying another target, it wants all combinations of `sample` and `outf` that you specified in `rule all`.

If you only want to pair `[Sample A]` with `[Variable Destination Folder A]` and so on, you'll need to change how Snakemake handles your `expand()` in `rule all`.

Right now, what you have is

```py
rule all:
    input:
        expand(os.path.join("{outf}","{sample}","methods.txt"), outf=OUTPREFIXES, sample=SAMPLES)
```

This pairs all prefixes in `OUTPREFIXES` with all samples in `SAMPLES`, which is the standard behavior of `expand()`. [You can specify a different combinatoric function](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#the-expand-function) in `expand()`, though - if you only want to combine the first sample with the first destination, the second with the second etc., your `rule all` should instead use `zip`, like so:

```py
rule all:
    input:
        expand(os.path.join("{outf}","{sample}","methods.txt"), zip, outf=OUTPREFIXES, sample=SAMPLES)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping explain the "zip" setting!

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you provided a sample sheet and minimal Snakefile to reproduce the error.

From what I can see, you get missing file error for `[Variable Destination Folder B]/[Sample A]/methods.txt` because you don't have code that actually creates that file. Also, it is a bit odd to have `outfolder` listed in `input`, but that may be due to something that happens earlier in the pipeline? I would do:

```
rule copy_folders:
    input:
        infolder = get_input_folder,
    output:
        outfolder = directory(get_output_folder),
        touch(os.path.join("{outf}","{sample}","methods.txt")),
    resources: ...
    shell: ...
```

I use `touch` to create the dummy file `methods.txt` that signals the completion of the rule - there may be other/better ways to handle the situation.

Note that the `directory` function shouldn't be used in the input directive.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I have removed directory() from the input section.

Comment: I think a comment is not ideal for explaining the sample pairing file.  I also want to remove some specifics from the public post.  However, the header for the comma-separated file is "FPID,Input,Output,Subfolder,FullOutSubfolder".  Thank you again for your feedback!