# Snakemake: Expand Incorrectly Defining Output Folders

Tags: python, wildcard, directory-structure, snakemake, expand

I have a workaround based upon [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72776216/snakemake-mismatched-wildcards-variable-values-for-output-rule), so I don't think this problem is especially urgent.

However, before applying code to a larger number of folders, I would like to see if I can better understand what went wrong in an earlier version of the code.

Here is the Snakemake code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

data = pd.read_csv("mapping_list.csv").set_index('Subfolder', drop=False)
SAMPLES = data["Subfolder"].tolist()
OUTPREFIXES = data["Output"].tolist()

def get_input_folder(wildcards):
    return data.loc[wildcards.sample]["Input"]

def get_output_folder(wildcards):
    return data.loc[wildcards.sample]["Output"]

rule all:
    input:
        expand(os.path.join("{outf}","{sample}"), zip, outf=OUTPREFIXES, sample=SAMPLES)

rule copy_folders:
    input:
        infolder = get_input_folder,
        outfolder = get_output_folder
    output:
        subfolder = directory(os.path.join("{outf}","{sample}"))
    resources:
        mem_mb=1000,
        cpus=1
    shell:
        "cp -R {input.infolder} {input.outfolder}"
```

I think that the problem is that the `{outf}` and `{sample}` variables are not being defined correctly.

For example, let's say `{outf}` can be further divided into **{outf-PREFIX}** and **{outf-SUBFOLDER}**, so `{outf}` is `{outf-PREFIX}/{outf-SUBFOLDER}`.

Here is the error message that I am seeing, with those placeholders instead of the observed values:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
InputFunctionException in line 22 of /path/to/Snakefile:
KeyError: '{outf-SUBFOLDER}'
Wildcards:
outf={outf-PREFIX}
sample={outf-SUBFOLDER}
```

***In other words, the value of {sample} is not being used.***  I am assuming that the problem relates to the `expand` command.

Instead, `{outf}` and `{sample}` are being defined from components that would define the full `{outf}` (**{outf-PREFIX}** and **{outf-SUBFOLDER}**).  So, I think the problem could solved if Snakemake instead created the following mapping:

```
outf={outf}
sample={sample}
```

I also encounter a similar problem with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

data = pd.read_csv("mapping_list.csv").set_index('FullOutSubfolder', drop=False)
FULLOUTS = data["FullOutSubfolder"].tolist()

def get_input_folder(wildcards):
    return data.loc[wildcards.sample]["Input"]

def get_output_folder(wildcards):
    return data.loc[wildcards.sample]["Output"]
    
rule all:
    input:
        expand("{sample}", sample=FULLOUTS)

rule copy_folders:
    input:
        infolder = get_input_folder,
        outfolder = get_output_folder
    output:
        subfolder = directory("{sample}")
    resources:
        mem_mb=1000,
        cpus=1
    shell:
        "cp -R {input.infolder} {input.outfolder}"
```

In that situation, the output folder path is being truncated as a wildcard (losing the equivalent of the original `{sample}`), similar to the truncated `{outf}` above.

*Can anybody please explain the problem or provide any suggestions?*

Thank you very much!

Sincerely,

Charles

***Update (7/7/2022)***: I believe that there was some confusion, so I hope that the additional information helps.

Here is an example with placeholder information for 2 lines similar to what would be seen in *mapping_list.csv*:

```
FPID,Input,Output,Subfolder,FullOutSubfolder
fp1,/path/to/InputFolderA/SampleA,/path/to/OutputPrefixA/OutputFolderA,SampleA,/path/to/OutputPrefixA/OutputFolderA/SampleA
fp2,/path/to/InputFolderB/SampleB,/path/to/OutputPrefixB/OutputFolderB,SampleB,/path/to/OutputPrefixB/OutputFolderB/SampleB
```

To use that example, there are no variables called *{outf-PREFIX}* and *{outf-SUBFOLDER}*.

Instead, these are the **intended** values for the 1st row:

`{outf}`=*/path/to/OutputPrefixA/OutputFolderA*

`{sample}`=*SampleA*

and these are the values ***incorrectly*** defined by Snakemake:

`{outf}`=*/path/to/OutputPrefixA*

`{sample}`=*OutputFolderA*

So, my understanding is that the intended value of `{sample}` is not being used, and both variables are being defined from splitting the path from `{outf}`.

Comment: One thing to try is to avoid using dashes in wildcard names, this can cause hard to debug errors. For example, consider changing `{outf-PREFIX}` to something like `{outf_PREFIX}`.

Comment: I'm going to partially repeat my comment in the other thread, sorry! Can you provide a toy dataset (i.e. the content of mapping_list.csv) to reproduce the bug?

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev I apologize about the confusion.  I am not defining any variables `{outf-PREFIX} ` or `{outf-SUBFOLDER}`.  Instead, Snakemake appears to be splitting the path provided for `{outf}` and not using the intended value for `{sample}`.   I hope that the additional example recommended by @dariober helps, but I was essentially trying to define 2 parts of the path that is provided for `{outf}`.

Comment: ah, ok, I am sorry, was a bit hard to follow. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still curious what caused the earlier problem.

However, if somebody else encounters the same problem, then I do have a workaround.

The details are in the following post:

[Snakemake: Mismatched Wildcards Variable Values for "output" Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72776216/snakemake-mismatched-wildcards-variable-values-for-output-rule)

Basically, I added extra shell script commands and I copied a small file into the output directly.  I then used the **small file as the endpoint**, instead of the copied output directory.